# jQuery dropdown toggle menu not working correctly! Plugin help please?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, menu, drop-down-menu

Check out the following: http://jsfiddle.net/marcsanders/hNN5T/

The menu functions as it should as far as I see, but when one of the dropdown menu links is clicked I think the close function fires and so the dropdown menu link is not navigated too.

I have also tried to port this to a plugin but not having much luck - http://jsfiddle.net/UKthc/

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return false was in the wrong place I think. Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.drop').click(function() {
            var li = $(this), active = li.hasClass('active');

            close();
            if (!active) {
                li.toggleClass('active').children('ul').toggle();
                return false;
            }

        });


    function close() {
        $('.drop').removeClass('active').children('ul').hide();
    }

    $(document).bind('click',function() {
        close();
    });
});
```

Comment: That seemed to sort it, can't believe it was that simple. Any idea on the plugin idea? The document bind click function seems to be ignored.

http://jsfiddle.net/UKthc/1/